# Add values recursively in data table using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have data table like this:

```
  ===================================================================
       ID   |  Parent ID  |   Parent Node    |    Name     |   Values  
  ===================================================================
       1    |      0      |  Primary Node    |    Master1  |     0
       2    |      0      |  Primary Node    |    Master2  |     0
       3    |      1      |    Master1       |    Group1   |     0
       4    |      2      |    Master2       |    Group2   |     0
       5    |      3      |     Group1       |    Child1   |     10
       6    |      4      |     Group2       |    Child2   |     20
       7    |      4      |     Group2       |    Child3   |     30
```

I need the Output like this:

```
  ===================================================================
       ID   |  Parent ID  |   Parent Node    |    Name     |   Values  
  ===================================================================
       1    |      0      |  Primary Node    |    Master1  |     10
       2    |      0      |  Primary Node    |    Master2  |     50
       3    |      1      |    Master1       |    Group1   |     10
       4    |      2      |    Master2       |    Group2   |     50
       5    |      3      |     Group1       |    Child1   |     10
       6    |      4      |     Group2       |    Child2   |     20
       7    |      4      |     Group2       |    Child3   |     30
```

Actually the table is in not correct order:

I tried the below recursive method to arrange it, but don't know to how to get the cumulative values according to the parent groups

```
public DataTable RecursiveTreeTable(DataTable table, String parentNode, String dataColumn)
{
    ParentNodeColumnName = parentNode;
    DataColumnName = dataColumn;
    TblTree = table.Copy();
    TblTree.Clear();
    if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt64(dr["ParentNodeId"]) == 0)
            {
                TblTree.ImportRow(dr);
                FillNodeChildren(Convert.ToInt64(dr["Id"]), table);
            }
        }
    }
    return TblTree;
}



public void FillNodeChildren(Int64 parentID, DataTable table)
{

    foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt64(dr["ParentNodeId"]) != 0)
        {
            if (object.Equals(dr["ParentNodeId"].ToString(), parentID.ToString()))
            {
                TblTree.ImportRow(dr);
                FillNodeChildren(int.Parse(dr["Id"].ToString()), table);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Webforms or winforms?

Comment: What about `FillNodeChildren(...)` returning the sum of all children.
_btw geh: `Convert.ToInt64(dr["Id"])` and `int.Parse(dr["Id"].ToString())`_ different methods, different types...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written my own logic, and its working fine :)

```
public DataTable AddingRecursive(DataTable table)
        {
            for (int i = table.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt64(table.Rows[i]["Parent ID"]) != 0)
                {
                    Int64 parentNode = Convert.ToInt64(table.Rows[i]["Parent ID"]);
                    Decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(table.Rows[i]["Values"]);
                    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                    {
                        if (parentNode == Convert.ToInt64(row["ID"]))
                        {
                            row["Values"] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["Values"]) + value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return table;
        }
```

Comment: tip: try to avoid `ToString()` / `ToDecimal()` conversions. Where is the recursion? I think this will only work with one level deep tree. I don't see the recursion. So children of children aren't calculated. I'll stick to mine ;-)

Comment: Yes i updated... I have done recursive using `RecursiveTreeTable` method.. and added all the respective parent child values using `AddingRecursive` method.. so i got my required output.. :) any way your idea is good, and thank you for your tip tooooooo....:)

Answer (score 1):

I made an example, but this is written in *notepad++* so no errorchecking etc. So you have to fix some minor typo's etc.

I would create a method that returns the sum of all children.

```
public DataTable RecursiveTreeTable(DataTable table, String parentNode, String dataColumn)
{
    ParentNodeColumnName = parentNode;
    DataColumnName = dataColumn;
    TblTree = table.Copy();
    TblTree.Clear();
    if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
        {
            var desRow = TblTree.NewRow();
            desRow.ItemArray = dr.ItemArray.Clone() as object[];
            desRow["Values"] = SumOfValuesForAllChildren(dr, table);
        }
    }
    return TblTree;
}



public decimal SumOfValuesForAllChildren(DataRow parentRow, DataTable table)
{
    var parentID = Convert.ToInt64(parentRow["Id"]);

    // start with the parent value.
    var result = Convert.ToDecimal(parentRow["Values"]);

    foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
    {
        var childParentId = Convert.ToInt64(dr["ParentNodeId"]);
        if (childParentId == parentID)
            // add the child values
            result += SumOfValuesForAllChildren(dr, table);

    }
    return result;
}
```

This method will scan all children over and over. This is not a optimal solution but might help solving your 'problem'.

Don't forget, this will give a stackoverflow on a circulair reference. *(the parent has it's child as parent)*

Comment: FillNodeChildren(DataRow, DataTable);  FillNodeChildren(Int64, DataTable);  How its possible ?

Comment: Fixed...   -> _notepad++_ shizzle

Comment: Thank you soo much for your support Langen !

Comment: So, my solution helped ;-)

Comment: Yes it helped to write my own logic ;-).. +1